# Install error matplotlib==3.0.0 by pip3 base on python3.6.9 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

My system has 2 versions of python
one is 2.7 .17the other is 3.6.9 and no pip2 ,
I just install pip3, and I use pip3 to install matplotlib==3.0.0
and i get the error code.

```
Collecting matplotlib==3.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/06/def4fb2620cbe671ba0cb6462cbd8653fbffa4acd87d6d572659e7c71c13/matplotlib-3.0.0.tar.gz (36.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 36.3MB 13kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [3.0.0]
                    python: yes [3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00)  [GCC
                            8.4.0]]
                  platform: yes [linux]
    
    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.13.3]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                            be found.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
    
    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
    
    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]
    
    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]
    
    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
                            * Try installing freetype with `apt-get install
                            * libfreetype6-dev` and pkg-config with `apt-get
                            * install pkg-config`
                            * Try installing png with `apt-get install
                            * libpng12-dev` and pkg-config with `apt-get install
                            * pkg-config`
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vdamltw3/matplotlib/
```

I try to solve it
like this

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

and this

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

but still got same error code
What should I do know?

Comment: Python 2.7, Python 3.6 and Ubuntu 18.04 are all end-of-life, and you will have a terrible time trying to use any modern library with them. If you can't upgrade your Ubuntu to something more modern, you can try using https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv to install a modern Python for your user.

Comment: (You could also try installing the development packages for freetype and libpng, since those are referred to in the "required packages" section as being missing.)

Comment: @AKX Does it still work ,If I still wants to use python3.6.9 to install matplotlib?

Comment: Actually, there _are_ pre-built binary wheels for Matplotlib even for Python 3.6 – you might want to try with a newer `pip`.

Comment: did you read error message? It shows problem with `freetype` and `png` and it suggests to use `apt` it install them. Did you try to do it?